# xsd schema application to xml document?

Tags: xml, xslt, mapping, quickbase

I am attempting to transfer data from a quickbase database to another application. I have the .xsd schema the receiving application will accept and the ability to export a flat .xml file from quickbase. Quickbase provides the ability to apply a .xsl style sheet to the .xml export which I assume would have the ability to apply the schema format to the export.The element names in the .xsd and element names in the .xml export match due to the quickbase fields being designed using the schema elements for the receiving app.

The problem I have is I do not know how to create the required .xsl. Are there (free) tools that can generate an xsl if you have an .xml  with correct data elements and the required .xsd? If so what would you recommend? If not, any recommendations on a way forward would be greatly appreciated.

I am currently using Eclipse EE with webtools xml plug-ins.

disclaimer -this is my first question on stackoverflow (or any forum for that matter) so please be patient with me if I'm totally off-base...I am a noob.

Thanks in advance,

Jimmy

Comment: You might want to look at [this Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772466/transform-xml-to-xml-using-xslt-based-on-xsd)

Comment: Thank you Hazzit...that was useful and led me to another post that displayed the xslt code for identity transform "copy.xsl" which may solve my problem. Does that solution seem viable?

Comment: An identity transformation is essentially a "no-op" on a set of data. Since you _do_ want to transform it into something else (something that validates against the xsd you've got), your transform will have to be something else. You might get further if you add information on the XML/XSD involved to your question. Others may then get you started with your XSLT even if they (like me) don't know any good semi-automatic tools do do this.